# Why do I get this error in Swift "Could not find member subscript"

Tags: swift

I'm trying to work with the dictionary object result returned after a facebook login. The result variable looks like this

```
 result = [ location: ["name": "Paris, France", "id": "34534999333"]  ]
```

and my goal is to access the location name.
I try this code:

```
 if let location = result["location"]?["name"] as? String {
              //do something      
      }
```

but I get the error "could not find member subscript."
I see nothing wrong with the logic of my code. If result["location"] exists, then look for the index "name" in it, cast it as a string, and if successful, set the constant "location" equal to it.

I could do what I want with a longer code but I just want to learn why Swift doesn't understand the code above.

Comment: isn't the key `location` in the dictionary also a string (missing quotes) ?

Comment: Is possible that the location is not of type `Dictionary` but `AnyObject`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect your problem is that `result` is an optional type.  <kbd>option</kbd>-click on the `result` variable.  If it is of type `NSDictionary?` or something like `[NSObject: AnyObject]?` then `result` will have to be unwrapped before you can use it.  I would first try:

```
if let location = result?["location"]?["name"] as? String {
    //do something      
}
```

If `result` is `AnyObject` or `AnyObject?`, I would suggest taking this a step at a time:

```
if let dict = result as? NSDictionary {
    if let location = dict["location"] as? NSDictionary {
        if let name = location["name"] as? String {
            // use name
        }
    }
}
```

You can compact the above into a single if:

```
if let name = ((result as? NSDictionary)?["location"] as? NSDictionary)?["name"] as? String {
    // use name
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It was of type AnyObject. May I ask why you casted it to NSDictionary and not just  Dictionary?

Comment: It is coming from an Objective-C API, so underneath it is an `NSDictionary`.  If you cast it to `Dictionary` you need to say what the types of the keys and values are.  You could cast to `[NSObject: AnyObject]` which is what an `NSDictionary` is, but it is easier to just say `NSDictionary`.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the apparent typo (the 'location' in the assignment to `result` should surely be a string literal `"location"`?), the optional downcast to `String` in the `if let` statement is unnecessary. Swift has already inferred the type - it knows that `result["location"]?["name"]` returns the type `String?`.

`as? String` should be producing a compiler warning, but I would not expect it to be "could not find member subscript" unless the compiler has got quite confused (which has been know at this relatively early stage in Swift's development!). Start by removing the downcast.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler was confused. The reasoning is that the "location:" in the original looks like a dictionary assignment but the key location also looks like a variable as written. Surrounding that value with quotes to make it a distinct dictionary key will produce the desired Dictionary object. You can unwrap the place information using the following syntax.

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import UIKit

let result = [  "location": ["name": "Paris, France", "id": "34534999333"]  ]

if let place = result["location"]?["name"]   {
    //do something
    print(place)

}
```

Option-clicking on any suspect variables after you've written the line of code would normally show a result type of << error type >> whenever the compiler is having an issue.